# Kendo UI Grid custom sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid in my application where the user wants the following functionality.

Scenerio

- There are 4 columns in the grid, let's call them A, B, C and D.
- Multiple columns are sortable and can be reordered.
- The default sort is column A, B, C, D
- If the user drags column C to be the first column, then the sort should be C, A, B, D.

I know there's a `columnOrder` event on the grid. Is this functionality possible? Is there an example anywhere or could someone give me direction on how to accomplish this functionality?

Thanks

Jim

Answer (score 1):

In the event handler you can get the new column order from: `this.columns`. Then you should compose the sorting criteria and apply it.

Something like:

```
        columnReorder: function() {
          var sort = [];
          $.each(this.columns, function(idx, elem) {
            // In my case order by those columns that start with "Ship" 
            if (elem.field.lastIndexOf("Ship", 0) === 0) {
              sort.push({field: elem.field, dir: "asc"});
            }
          });
          this.dataSource.sort(sort);
        },
```

Following a runnable example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      type: "odata",
      transport: {
        read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
      },
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {                         
            OrderID: { type: "number" },           
            ShipCountry: { type: "string" },
            ShipCity: { type: "string" },
            ShipName: { type: "string" },
            OrderDate: { type: "date" },
            ShippedDate: {type: "date" }
          }
        }
      },
      pageSize: 15
    },
    height: 550,
    sortable: true,
    reorderable: true,
    resizable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columnReorder: function() {
      var sort = [];
      $.each(this.columns, function(idx, elem) {
        if (elem.field.lastIndexOf("Ship", 0) === 0) {
          sort.push({field: elem.field, dir: "asc"});
        }
      });
      this.dataSource.sort(sort);
    },
    columns: [
      {
        field: "OrderID",
        title: "ID",
        width: 80
      },
      {
        field: "ShipCity",
        title: "Ship City"
      },
      {
        field: "ShipName",
        title: "Ship Name"
      },
      {
        field: "ShippedDate",
        title: "Shipped Date",
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
        width: 200
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common-office365.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.office365.min.css" />

<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```